# how to copy Stucture, Constraints and triggers from one table to another?

Tags: postgresql

with this command "create table demo as table niu_trans_stats with data" we successfully copied structure and data from the original table but we also want to copy constraints and triggers, Please help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you db support LIKE you can do the following. It will copy the constraints - `CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE original_table;`
2. Other way it do all stuff manually

   ```
   CREATE TABLE new_table (
     column1 datatype1 CONSTRAINT constraint_name1,
     column2 datatype2 CONSTRAINT constraint_name2,
     column3 datatype3 CONSTRAINT constraint_name3,
     ...
     CONSTRAINT table_constraint_name1,
     CONSTRAINT table_constraint_name2,
     ...
   );
   ```

Then fill the data.

```
INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM original_table;
```

Im not sure about triggers, looks like they should be added manually